# Pandas, fill new column with existing values dependant on conditions of another column

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, match

This is my special list
`special_list = [0,4,7]`

I am trying to create a new column named "price_v2" where all fields are `None`, except the ones where the numbers in the "numbers_index" column match those in my special_list, if there is a match I'd like to use the values in the "price" column to fill out the the values in "price_v2".

This is my dataframe

```
                         price  numbers_index
2017-08-17 04:00:00      4261   0
2017-08-17 04:01:00      4253   1
2017-08-17 04:02:00      4267   2
2017-08-17 04:03:00      4275   3
2017-08-17 04:04:00      4295   4
2017-08-17 04:05:00      4310   5
2017-08-17 04:06:00      4360   6
2017-08-17 04:07:00      4350   7
```

Desired Output:

```
                         price  numbers_index  price_v2
2017-08-17 04:00:00      4261   0              4261
2017-08-17 04:01:00      4253   1              None
2017-08-17 04:02:00      4267   2              None
2017-08-17 04:03:00      4275   3              None
2017-08-17 04:04:00      4295   4              4295
2017-08-17 04:05:00      4310   5              None
2017-08-17 04:06:00      4360   6              None
2017-08-17 04:07:00      4350   7              4350
```

I have tried the following code below however it did not work because my special list is shorter than the length of the pandas column. Can anyone help me with this?

`df['price_v2'] = np.where(df['numbers_index'] == special_list, df['price'], None)`

`ValueError: Lengths must match to compare`

Comment: Use `isin`: `np.where(df['numbers_index'].isin(special_list), df['price'], None)`

Comment: You can use: `df['numbers_index'].mask(df['numbers_index'].isin(special_list), df['price'])`